# Sessions#New Wrong Number of Arguments Error after upgrading to Rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I updated to Rails4, and am now getting "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)".

```
.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => "search-form home-search"}) do |f|
    = f.email_field :email, :id => 'beta_form', :class => 'beta_form',  :placeholder => 'Email'
    = f.password_field :password, :id => 'beta_form', :class => 'beta_form',  :placeholder => 'Password'
    = f.submit "Sign In", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block beta_submit center-block'
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

Answer (score 1):

All set.  For some reason, I had to delete gem 'meta-search' after upgrading.

Comment: if you use meta-search, check out ransack https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack  works better with Rails4